# Laptop screen is disabled when external monitor is plugged in during or prior to booting

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I've got an external monitor hooked up on my laptop. If the monitor is plugged in when I boot, any time before Windows loads, the laptop screen is disabled, and is not recognized even after I log in (so Fn-F4 is not an option). There's nothing in the BIOS regarding screens.

The easy workaround is to unplug the monitor before booting up and plug it as soon as Windows stars loading, but that's got annoying very fast, especially on soft restarts. I'm looking for something a bit more permanent.

Laptop make & model is HP G72, Windows version is Home Premium 64b SP1 and display adapter is listed as Intel HD Graphics.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked in Display properties > Settings > Advanced > Intel Graphics tab, for multi-monitor display options?

Comment: @Tog I'll need some help with that, I've checked everything under the `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Display` path, but I'm not sure that's the same as yours. I played around with Intel's Graphics and Media Control Panel tray app, no luck.

Comment: @Tog I think you mean the `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution\Advanced Settings\Intel tab` path, checked there, no luck, the tray app I mentioned above comes up when I click properties.

Comment: This sounds like normal behavior although it might be annoying. I've come across laptops like that.

Comment: As far as I remember, my Acer TravelMate C300 worked that way until video out died. **EDIT**: I missed the part where your laptop's monitor doesn't come back up at login. That's definitely abnormal.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a setting in the BIOS for the default display, changing this from 'External VGA' (or similar) to 'Onboard Display' (or similar) should resolve the problem and use the 'laptop screen' as default - regardless of what you have plugged in externally.